# Admin login as another user with Symfony2 Security

Tags: php, symfony

I have a system, that has 2 roles (admins and users). Authentication made using Security Symfony2 component. Admin doesn't know user password. But he should be able to login into the system as user. I have a grid with all users and want to add buttons like "Login as this user". How can I make it?

I have tried, but no prfit:

```
$userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrameFoxBackEndBundle:User');
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->setUser($userRepo->find(1));
```

Comment: If you want the admin to be login with any user id make a global password in users table and if admin comes online with any user id with that global password simply login him

Comment: A global password field which only admin will know and it will work for all users in your table

Comment: @Umair Iqbal, sorry but it's a curve solution. See Bgi answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this code :

```
// use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken
$entity = $userRepo->find(1);

// Authentication
// create the authentication token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $entity,
    null,
    'user_db',
    $entity->getRoles());
// give it to the security context
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: I know that UsernamePasswordToken works, but in this problem l3l0' answer is imho better

Answer (score 11):

Why not use built-in [switch user](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html) option?

Comment: Note to people coming across this, the new link is located here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use Symfony core support for that manner.
Have a look at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html.

You define a role which is allowed to switch user, and a parameter in the url that allows you to switch the user.